# Does TypeORM supports temporary table?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, express, typeorm

I haven’t seen any related docs about Temporary table with typeORM.
After trying to create temporary table, I ended up with repository not found error.

```
const manager = getManager();

const res = await manager.query(`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "XXX"(
    "highest_score" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "is_self" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "position" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "twitter_avatar" TEXT,
    "twitter_handle" TEXT
 );`);
console.log('TABLE CREATED', res);
// Insert Data
await Promise.all(
  data.results.map((player) =>
    manager.query(
      `INSERT INTO "XXX" (highest_score, is_self, position, twitter_avatar, twitter_handle) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);`,
      [
        player.highest_score,
        player.is_self,
        player.position,
        player.twitter_avatar,
        player.twitter_handle,
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

The Error

```
{"code":"42P01","file":"parse_relation.c","length":119,"level":"error","line":"1381","message":"relation \"XXX\" does not exist","name":"QueryFailedError","parameters":[465222,4258702253,7,"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1515429535164117000/bHV3CNQl_normal.png","Massacro1261"],"position":"13","query":"INSERT INTO \"XXX\" (highest_score, is_self, position, twitter_avatar, twitter_handle) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);","routine":"parserOpenTable","severity":"ERROR"}
```

Comment: it seems good to try make all in a one 'call'